# Unable to remove Settings.bundle

Tags: xcode, ios4, settings.bundle

My app used to use the Settings.bundle to load settings from the user, but then I changed it to have the settings in the application. I have all the code completed, and it works. The next step is to remove any of the code for the settings.bundle.

I have removed the code, and the settings.bundle itself, but when I compile, I still get the same bundle shows up in the settings app. Did I forget to remove something? or is this some type of glitch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean your project and rebuild it - during simple build xcode may just update executable in application bundle but don't touch old resources/bundles in it.

Comment: this is not working for me, deleted settings bundle, cleaned all targets, restarted simulator.  still shows up, i wish to delete the settings bundle without users having to delete the app and reinstall, since if they do they would also loose their data

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue as @zambono. I've removed the settings bundle and now deal with the settings in-app. The bundle still shows in the Settings app, unless I delete the application. Do we know what happens to end users when they update ? Can they still see our app in Settings, or is it removed ? Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a bug in iOS 6, maybe also iOS 5. I reported it to Apple but got no response yet. Has anybody been able to confirm yet if the Settings.bundle will also not be removed upon upgrade from the App Store on the customer's device? I tried to simulate the installation with via ad hoc, without the bundle being removed.